# What is a partial dual-issue pipeline?

Tags: arm, pipeline, microprocessors

I understand that some microprocessors such as ARM Cortex A8 and A9 support dual issue pipelining i.e. they can sustain executing two instructions per cycle. I didn't quite understand the partial dual-issue as stated in [Table 1](http://www.bdti.com/InsideDSP/2011/11/17/ARM) for A7.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the context:

> The Cortex-A7 is an in-order, partial dual-issue machine. The dual integer pipelines are eight stages long; the Cortex-A7 combines full ALU (labeled "integer" in Figure 1 above) and partial ALU (labeled "dual-issue") structures, thereby enabling dual-issue instruction execution for some integer operations. Digital signal processing algorithm implementers should note, however, that both conventional multiplication and NEON SIMD operations are single issue-only (the load-store pipeline, as its name implies, handles memory read and write accesses). And all coders should note that the Cortex-A7 does not include the additional transistor- and power-consuming circuitry necessary to handle out-of-order instruction processing.

Clearly, partial dual issue means dual issue for some instructions, but not others.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on **some instructions**?

Comment: For example "some instructions" does not include the multiplication and NEON SIMD operations!   I imagine that there is a more detailed / complete listing in the Cortex-A7 technical documentation.